# linux: How to get wireless ssid without root permission?

Tags: linux, ssid, iwconfig

Is there any way to get current wireless SSID without root permission?

iwconfig tells me ESSID, but only if I run it as root.

Comment: What happens if you run it as a regular user? What Linux distribution do you use? Also, you may find [unix.se] a more suitable site for such questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code of the `iwconfig` ([wireless_tools](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html)), you'll see this line:

```
iwconfig.c:639: if(iw_get_ext(skfd, ifname, SIOCGIWESSID, &wrq) < 0)
```

This line is responsible for the get of ESSID ([wireless.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/wireless.h?v=2.6.35#L271)). And i think that only root have permissions (out of the box) to do this, so the function `iw_get_ext` (defined in `iwlib.h` from `wireless_tools` package) which call `ioctl` will return `EPERM` (`Operation not permitted`).

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*
 * Wrapper to extract some Wireless Parameter out of the driver
 */
static inline int
iw_get_ext(int                  skfd,           /* Socket to the kernel */
           const char *         ifname,         /* Device name */
           int                  request,        /* WE ID */
           struct iwreq *       pwrq)           /* Fixed part of the request */
{
  /* Set device name */
  strncpy(pwrq->ifr_name, ifname, IFNAMSIZ);
  /* Do the request */
  return(ioctl(skfd, request, pwrq));
}
```

You have 2 solutions:

1. Use the `setuid` to allow the user to use `iwconfig` command:

   `sudo chmod u+s /sbin/iwconfig`
2. You can also try to do some hacking with the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability which allow some specific capabilities to a specific user. Here some links about `CAP_NET_ADMIN`:

http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/mar/19/sniffing-wireshark-non-root-user/

http://peternixon.net/news/2012/01/28/configure-tcpdump-work-non-root-user-opensuse-using-file-system-capabilities/

http://www.lids.org/lids-howto/node48.html

http://lwn.net/Articles/430462/

Finally you can use `strace` to trace all system calls and to confirm that `ioctl` call is the responsible for this:

as `root` do this:

```
#strace /sbin/iwconfig your_interface_name > strace_iwconfig_root.log
```

And the same as **normal user**:

```
$strace /sbin/iwconfig your_interface_name > strace_iwconfig_normal.log
```

And compare the results.

Comment: Great! chmod u+s or doing something with CAP_NET_ADMIN and CAP_NET_ADMIN both work very well. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can kind of get around this if `network-manager` is installed on the system. Then you can (depending on the version) use `nm-tool` or `nmctl`. My geolocation library has example code, see: https://github.com/privatwolke/geolocation

Comment: How about $ nmcli dev